# How to make the log in section can go in to an box?

Tags: html, css, box

```
<body>
...
<style>
   #box {
     width: 500px;
     height: 500px;
     border: 1px solid black;
   }
...
</style>
...
  <div class="Log-in">
    <div id="">
      <h1 id="center">Log in</h1>
      <div class="input-box">
        <input type="text" id="name" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-radius: 0px;" placeholder="Enter your name">
        <i class='bx bx-user' id="Center" style="float: right; left: 15px; top: 132px;"></i>
        <input type="password" id="password" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-radius: 0px; top: 130px;" placeholder="Enter your password">
        <i class='bx bx-lock-alt' id="Center" style="float: right; left: 15px; top: 111px;"></i>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" id="Center" style="width: 170px; top: 130px;" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
      <label id="Center" style="height: auto; top: 130px;"><input type="checkbox">Remember me</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

> on here the box the the (css) code I made a box but the box is not go in the a log-in section so i wanted to that the box is boarded to the log-in section

[log-in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm040.png)
make it there has a box out the log-in section.

Comment: What box are you referring to? There is no element with an ID of `box`. Also you can't re-use IDs. They must be unique on a page. You have at least 3 with the ID of "Center".

Answer (score 1):

`id` which must be unique in the whole document. Its purpose is to identify the element when linking. You should use [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) attribute instead of using [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) with same value again and again. Your code is incomplete I suggest you learn about [HTML Forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form).

Here's an example of the usage of the form tag.

```
<form action="/log-in.html" method="POST">
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-radius: 0px;"
            placeholder="Enter your name">
        <i class='bx bx-user' class="Center" style="float: right; left: 15px; top: 132px;"></i>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password"
            style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-radius: 0px; top: 130px;"
            placeholder="Enter your password">
        <i class='bx bx-lock-alt' class="Center" style="float: right; left: 15px; top: 111px;"></i>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="Center" style="width: 170px; top: 130px;" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
    <label class="Center" style="height: auto; top: 130px;"><input type="checkbox" name="Remember">Remember me</label>
</form>
```

For your ease I would like you to refer you to [w3schools HTML tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/html/)